# CDS for Funding

Tags: derivatives, cds, credit-derivatives, sovereign-cds

I was wondering if anyone is familiar with how credit default swaps can be used for corp funding and financing.

I came across an old case where a bank created a funding structure for a client (asset manager).  However, I'm not familiar with how this takes place.

Any insight on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Faisal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right.

**What is a CDS?**

*"agreement that the seller of the CDS will compensate the buyer [...] in the event of a loan default [...]. 
The buyer of the CDS makes a series of payments (the CDS "fee" or "spread") to the seller [...]"*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_default_swap

**How this could be used?**

The Investmentbank could have helped the Asset Manager to sell the protection against the default of a bond or a basket of bonds, as an income generating strategy.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Basically like selling options to generate income to finance other investments.